vscode how to disable .ssh exposure into devcontainer?
By default vscode "Dev Containers" extension seems to expose the contents of ~/.ssh/known_hosts and all my ssh keys ssh-add -l (all private keys not added to ssh-agent) of my local machine to the dev container that is being created.
This seems to be a feature established sometime in 2019. However there is no trace of documentation how this can be disabled.
The GitHub issue referenced above does refer to remote extensions however the remote-ssh isn't installed on my vscode profile.
The vscode v1.41 release notes state:

Forwarding SSH agent
The local SSH agent is now forwarded into the container. For example, if you are using SSH to checkout your repository, Git support seamlessly works when opening the folder in a container and the key is registered with the local SSH agent.

Does anybody know how to disable this?
The setting from vscode "Remote - SSH" extension "remote.SSH.enableAgentForwarding": false doesn't seem to be working.
